# How to modulate the size of the nodes of a network analysis with a certain value for each edge?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nodes, networkx, network-analysis

in the current graph the size of the nodes is given by the "count" of the arcs (e.g. node a going to a and b will be larger than the other two nodes that have no arcs to other nodes).
the excel file is composed as follows:

- column 0 (date[0]) = value of the oriented arc
- column 1 (data[1]) = node a (node from where the oriented arc starts)
- column 2 (data[2]) = node b (node from where the directed arc arrives)

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd

file = '/a/example.xlsx'

G= nx.DiGraph()
nations = []

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    data= sheet.row_slice(row)
    Orig = data[1].value
    Bene = data[2].value
    nations.append((Orig, Bene))
    
pos = nx.planar_layout(G)
betCent = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True, endpoints=True)
node_colors = [20000.0*G.degree(v) for v in G]
node_sizes =  [v*7000 for v in betCent.values()]
 
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True,
                 node_color = node_colors,
                 node_size = node_sizes)
plt.axis('off')
G.add_edges_from(nations)
nx.draw(G,with_labels= True, verticalalignment='bottom')
plt.show()
```

Here the sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weight':['50'] * 4 + ['500'] * 5 + ['20'] * 3 + ['100'],
    'node a':['pippo', 'pippo', 'pippo', 'pluto', 'pippo', 'pippo',
             'pluto', 'topolino', 'qua', 'minnie', 'winnie', 'pippo', 'qua'],
    'node b':['pluto', 'qua', 'minnie', 'pluto', 'winnie', 'pippo',
             'pluto', 'topolino', 'qua', 'qua', 'pippo', 'qua', 'qua'],
    })
```

Comment: Could you add a working example? Do you want the node size to be related to the sum of the edge (arc) values (i.e. `data[0]`)?

Comment: Would be great to have a hardcoded graph example. The question is not about import from excel so remove all that.

Comment: @AveragePythonEnjoyer exactly, e.g. I will have the size of node 'a' larger than that of node 'b' and 'c' if I have three lines for example:

(Data[0]) (Data[1]) (Data[2])
 10        a                  b
 20        a                  c
  5         c                  b

Comment: @mozway sorry i don't understand your clarification request

Comment: @MarcoMarcellino Please provide a dataframe so we do not have to create it ourself, but where the logic is clear:)

Comment: You just need to add an attribute to the edgse; representing the weight;  and then sum over the incoming edges.

Comment: @AveragePythonEnjoyer I have added an example dataframe in the application. I hope this is what you asked for :)

Comment: This is exactly what I expected! thank you very much! of course there are cycles but this is normal for the df I used:) thanks @AveragePythonEnjoyer

Comment: Because you have mutliple edges per node pair… See the comment under my answer. You have to use `G=nx.MultiDiGraph()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I show, how to calculate the sum of edge weights of outgoing edges and scale the nodes accordingly:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weight':['50'] * 4 + ['500'] * 5 + ['20'] * 3 + ['100'],
    'node a':['pippo', 'pippo', 'pippo', 'pluto', 'pippo', 'pippo',
             'pluto', 'topolino', 'qua', 'minnie', 'winnie', 'pippo', 'qua'],
    'node b':['pluto', 'qua', 'minnie', 'pluto', 'winnie', 'pippo',
             'pluto', 'topolino', 'qua', 'qua', 'pippo', 'qua', 'qua'],
    })


G= nx.DiGraph()
nations = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    Orig = row[1]
    Bene = row[2]
    weight = float(row[0]) 
    #add the wight of each edge as an attribute 
    nations.append((Orig, Bene, {'weight':weight}))

#generate Graph
G.add_edges_from(nations)

#iterate over nodes and sum the weight of their outgoing edges, save on graph as node attribute
nodes_weight = {}
for n in G.nodes():
    nodes_weight[n]={'node_weight':sum([d['weight'] for o,b,d in G.out_edges(n, data=True)])}
    
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes_weight)  

#draw graph
pos = nx.planar_layout(G)

#calculate node size from attribute
node_sizes =  [v*2 for v in list(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'node_weight').values())]

#similar if you want to change edge sizes
edge_sizes = [v/200 for v in list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight').values())]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True,
                 width = edge_sizes,
                 node_size = node_sizes)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Use `G = nx.MultiDiGraph()` in case you have multiple edges between the same nodes!

Comment: i used MultiDiGraph() but is the same. @AveragePythonEnjoyer

Comment: If you use the MutliDiGraph constructor they are not anymore

Comment: Unfortunally with this constructor the situation is the same...if you change the code, do you see differences?

Comment: I adjusted the code: At the bottom there was a second draw command. Just delete: `nx.draw(G,with_labels= True, verticalalignment='bottom')`

Comment: Now is perfect! code works! thank you very much :)